# CloudantDB: using db.get without id

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have a table:

```
id: 001
name: test
provider_id:ABC123
```

and I try to query with provider_id and get a error message, but not with id:001

```
db.get("ABC123", function(err, data) {
    // The rest of your code goes here. For example:
    console.log("Found id:", data);
  });
```

Please give me your thoughts how to run successfully db.get + provider_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `db.get` without the ID. However you can use either Query or Views to find the document you are looking for.

With query you can use a selector such as {"provider_id":"ABC123"}  to find the documents which contain that provider id.

With views you can use the `provider_id` as the key and the doc id or `null` as the value, such as:

```
function (doc) {
    emit(doc.provider_id, doc._id);
}
```

If you are using `null` as the value, you should use the `include_docs=true` option for the request. See your library's documentation on how to use views and query.